# Scene not being presented in SpriteKit

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

I'm making a game using SpriteKit.
I'm checking if the player is dead in the update method, like this:

```
-(void)update:(CFTimeInterval)currentTime
{
    if (self.player.dead) {
        [self gameOver];
    }
}
```

The `gameOver` method is the following:

```
-(void)gameOver {
    SKView * skView = (SKView *)self.view;
    GameOverScene *gameOver = [GameOverScene sceneWithSize:skView.bounds.size];
    gameOver.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;
    [skView presentScene:gameOver transition:[SKTransition doorsOpenHorizontalWithDuration:1.0]];
}
```

For some reason the `GameOver` scene is not being presented, instead the update method of the current screen keeps getting called. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you ever set the `dead` property of the player to YES?

Comment: Yes, that's done in another class, i did an NSLog when the player is dead to test it

Comment: For debugging purposes insert an NSLog in the if statement in the update method, and another in the gameOver method. Are either being called?

Comment: i added NSLog at both places, both are being called, but the scene is not changing

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem may be that the **self.player.dead** flag keeps evaluating to **YES** over and over again inside the **update** method, calling **[self gameOver]** numerous times and never actually completing the transition due to the 1 second duration; you could easily test this with a breakpoint or logging. Try calling **self.player.dead = NO** in the **-(void)gameOver** method before you present the new scene.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following and see if it makes a difference:

```
- (void)gameOver {
    SKScene *gameOver = [[GameOverScene alloc] initWithSize:self.size];
    SKTransition *doors = [SKTransition doorsOpenVerticalWithDuration:1.0];
    [self.view presentScene:gameOver transition:doors];
}
```

Also, make sure that gameOver is being called from the current scene.